# Logstash как правильно написать фильтр?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Подскажите как правильно распарсить

Имеем лог

```
Sat Oct 29 10:10:10 2019, src=node1, dst=node2, unq-id=123456, ........
```

Как правильно распарить дату и разобрать по индексам ключ значение не всё поля обязательные разделитель ", "
ещё есть поля содержащие даты в аналогичном формате их бы тоже правильно проиндексировать

Answer (score 0):

Ваш лог парсится так:

%{WORD:day_of_week} %{MONTH:month} %{NUMBER:day} %{TIME:time} %{YEAR:year}, src=%{WORD:src}, dst=%{WORD:dst}, unq-id=%{WORD:unq-id}

Все парттерны для грока доступны [тут](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns): дата, время, таймстампы.

Выбирайте нужные значения форматов.

Comment: Поля есть не обязательные, но они должны быть в базе. Предполагаю, что это решается через kv

Comment: либо еще один шаблон в match добавляйте